# How to reduce the video file size using the compression after adding noise?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add noise to the video file. The goal is to introduce noise in the video and then save it.

Current approach:

- Iterate over the frames of the video.
- Add noise to each frame then save it. # Adding gaussian noise from skimage
- Finally, merge the frames and save the video

Psuedo Code

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(clip_file_path)
while frame < end:
   ret_val, input_image = cam.read()
   input_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   noisy_img = add_noise(input_image, mode) # Adding gaussian noise from skimage
   save_frame()
```

Merge the frames

```
frame_rate = 30
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, codec, frame_rate, (width, height))
for frame in range(starting_frame, ending_frame):
    image = cv2.imread(frame_path_template.format(frame_path=full_extracted_frames_path, pid=pid,
                                                  exercise_type=exercise_type,
                                                  frame_number=frame))
    out.write(image)
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

These are the file size obtained:

- Original video file: 1.5 MB
- Video obtained after merging: 53.7 MB
- Video obtained after using compression: 39.6 MB
  `ffmpeg -i P33_R.mp4  -vcodec libx264 output1.mp4`
- Video obtained after using compression and crf 28: 16.2 MB
  `ffmpeg -i P33_R.mp4  -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 output1.mp4`

I would like to have the final file in the same size as the original one. Is it really possible to do that?

Comment: *"I would like to have the final file in the same size as the original one."* Why?

Comment: @llogan, I was just wondering if it is possible or not? Does including the noise mean file size should have also increase?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to get an output that's approximately the same size as the input. But it does not mean that it's a good idea to do so. Input file size is not a good metric to use as a basic for quality analysis. Not all formats are the same, not all encoders of the same format are equal, noise increases complexity which makes it harder to compress which increases bitrate requirements. Also [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) must be accounted for. Seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is the actual goal here?

Comment: @llogan, Thanks for the reply. I will be using these videos for classification using deep learning. So I wanted them to be as small as possible.

Comment: Use the highest `-crf` value that gives an acceptable quality. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).